# Index error occurs when trying to use an event listener

Tags: events, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to add a touch event listener to the image object being loaded. Although this is practically an exact copy and paste from the documentation:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/EventDispatcher/addEventListener.html

It returns the following error:

36: attempt to index local 'object' (a nil value)

```
local t = {}
local img = {}
local i = 1

local function showImages ()
    local function networkListenerImg( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
            print ( "Network error - download failed" )
        else
            event.target.alpha = 0
            transition.to( event.target, { alpha = 1.0 } )
        end
    end

    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        img[#img + 1] = v
    end

    local object = display.loadRemoteImage( event.params.chapter .. img[i], "GET", networkListenerImg, img[i], system.TemporaryDirectory, 50, 50 )

    function object:touch( event )
        if event.phase == "began" then
            print( "You touched the object!" )
            return true
        end
    end

    object:addEventListener( "touch", object )

end
```

The table, t, is populated elsewhere in the code and is populated properly.

Comment: Make sure that `object` is NOT `nil`. Also I don't see declaration of `event.params.chapter` in your code.

Comment: Event.params.chapter is a value passed from the previous scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you didn't mention which of those lines is line 36 (there are only 28 lines there), I can still see your error. The issue is that `object` is and always will be `nil`: `display.loadRemoteImage()` does not return anything, see [this](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/loadRemoteImage.html).

What you need to do is have your listener callback capture `object`, which must be declared before the callback is. The callback should then set the value of object to the results of the download. Like so...

```
local t = {}
local img = {}
local i = 1

local function showImages ()

    local object
    local function networkListenerImg( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
            print ( "Network error - download failed" )
        else
            event.target.alpha = 0
            transition.to( event.target, { alpha = 1.0 } )
            -- fill in code to save the download object into "object"
        end
    end

    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        img[#img + 1] = v
    end

    display.loadRemoteImage( event.params.chapter .. img[i], "GET", networkListenerImg, img[i], system.TemporaryDirectory, 50, 50 )

    function object:touch( event )
        if event.phase == "began" then
            print( "You touched the object!" )
            return true
        end
    end

    object:addEventListener( "touch", object )

end
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the problem.